# Seeking free or recent aerial imagery

Tags: imagery, united-kingdom

Is it possible to view either live or very recent (past few days) aerial imagery for UK?

Ideally images would be satellite imagery, high resolution and free.

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: sentinel, landsat, modis are all free, anything with higher resolution will probably cost you.

Comment: Where can I buy high resolution aerial imagery?

Comment: Have a look at [PlanetScope](https://docs.sentinel-hub.com/api/latest/data/planet-scope/)?